# Select only the values present multiple times in a list C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that might contain duplicate values and my requirement is to get a sub-list or something that contains only the duplicate values. For example, consider the following List

```
Cat
Dog
Dog
Mouse
Cat
Dog
Mouse
Cat
Elephant
```

Now I want to extract only Cat and Dog since they are present 3 times each. This 3 times each might change, might be 4 might be 5 or something else.

Is there a Linq query that can help me extract this?

Thanks! I'm just learning Linq so this question might sound a little stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *group* your items and then get those groups that has as many items as you want:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 3)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToList();
```

If you don't know the count beforehand and you want items that are most frequent in the list, you need to get the count first:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x).ToList();
var count = groups.Max(g => g.Count());

var items = groups.Where(g => g.Count() == count)
                  .Select(g => g.Key)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

I initially learned LINQ the best by using the query syntax, simply because of the explicit naming and lack of lambda operators (although I really like the method syntax now, and usually prefer it for brevity). Group the items in the list into groups, then select the Key which matches the count you specify in the "where" clause. Simply change the "count" variable to change the criteria (3, 4, 5, whatever you want, etc.)

```
int count = 3;

var matches = (from item in list
               group item by item into itemGroup
               where itemGroup.Count() == count
               select itemGroup.Key).ToList();
```

Also, LINQPad is an awesome tool for testing out LINQ queries and playing with different syntax. I think it even comes with preloaded examples if I'm not mistaken.